# If $x+y+z=xyz$, prove that $\frac{2x}{1-x^{2}}+\frac{2y}{1-y^{2}}+\frac{2z}{1-z^{2}}=\frac{2x}{1-x^{2}}\cdot\frac{2y}{1-y^{2}}\cdot\frac{2z}{1-z^{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do i proceed with this question? In the book, in solution they have taken $x=\tan A,\ y=\tan B,z=\tan C$. But, isn't it wrong as we have to prove this generally. Please help

Comment: That *is* generally, as $\tan$ can take any value.

Comment: Ok so since, tan and x have the same range, it is a fair assumption right?

Comment: Yes, that's right :-)